# Seeing a generic 500 internal error, how to view detailed error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-server-2008

On my production server, I just deployed a asp.net web application.

I am seeing a generic '500 internal server error'.

How can I view a detailed error temporarily until I fix the problem?

I already have:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="error.aspx"/>
```

Comment: There are usually detailed error logs in the Event Log (`eventvwr.msc`), either under Windows Logs -> Application, or under the IIS log in Apps & Services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<customErrors mode="Off" />` is usually enough. But if you have messed up with some IIS configuration it won't even reach your web.config which might explain why you are seeing this generic 500 error message. Take a look at the Event Log (`eventvwr.msc`) of the server which might contain additional information about the error. There could really be lots of possible reasons (.NET framework misconfiguration, application pool or virtual directory misconfiguration, missing access rights to some folders, ...)

That's the reason why you should have a staging server which has the same configuration as your production server - it would allow you to test your configuration before shipping.

Comment: which category in the event log?

Comment: ok I just viewed the site locally on the server, and it says "An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode."

Comment: @Blankman, right, does it say which setting? If not you could show your web.config file so that we can tell you.

Answer (score 2):

Change IIS Error Pages feature settings to "Detailed errors" or try to run the app from the server where it's deployed.

Answer (score 1):

If the error page is coming from IIS because of some configuration being incorrect, you can try using [Failed Request Tracing](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/266/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis/).